# SPO: Cannot access preservation hold library

Tags: library, access

When I click on the link "Preservation Hold Library" on the SPO-site (Office 365):

```
https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/{user}/_layouts/15/storman.aspx
```

This link leads me to:

```
https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/{user}/_layouts/15/storman.aspx?root=PreservationHoldLibrary
```

On this site I got the following error (German):

```
Das hat leider nicht geklappt.
Es ist ein unerwarteter Fehler aufgetreten.
TECHNISCHE DETAILS



Führen Sie die Problembehandlung mit Microsoft SharePoint Foundation aus.
Korrelations-ID: 964aec9e-b0ab-0000-a704-f611283297e2
```

What can i do to access the preservation hold library?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please browse this url: `https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/{user}/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx`  and click the Preservation Hold Library from here.

Make sure you are Site collection / Onedrive Admin as it will not be visible to others.

Comment: the link is working, thank you!